# Caching SmartCard PIN in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, smartcard

I am installing an application for signing scanned documents with a smart card certificate. The trouble is that the application is asking for the PIN for each document it has to sign, and it is not operative.

In another bussiness where the same application is in use I know that they only need to introduce the PIN once per scanning session. Both them and us are working on Windows XP.

The question is twofold:

- There is a method to cache the smart card PINs on Windows XP?
- When I compare our installation with that of the other bussiness, where should I look at? OS configuration? Smart card drivers? It is just an application issue?

TIA